# error while using python- selenium package

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to a basic python script for connecting to a web browser using the selenium package. The error log as shown is posted below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "F:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "F:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/WinPython/WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5/python-3.5.2.amd64/py_codes/python_org_search.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "F:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "F:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: Exception log is not enough to understand the problem. Show your code also

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path which already has the answer

Comment: @Andersson here is the code                                                            from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()

Answer (score 0):

From `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`, it is clear that you need to add `geckodriver` to your system path, more specifically the folder that contains `geckodriver.exe` should be added to the system path.

To do that, run `cmd.exe` as an administrator and run the following command:

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Path\to\geckodriver.exe\;"
```

Replace `C:\Path\to\geckodriver.exe\` with your exact path to the folder that contains `geckodriver.exe`

**Edit:**

You can download the `exe` file from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, extract it somewhere, let's say `C:\geckodriver`. Now, you have your file like this `C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe` and you need to add `C:\geckodriver` to your system path. And, run your script in a new console.

Comment: there is no geckodriver.exe all i found was a txt file named geckodriver which was generated in the same folder in which the python file containing the code was situated @ettanany

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, if you did not download and extract the exe file before, then you will need to do that by following the link above.